# Get message_id of Telegram bot sendPoll message php

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I have written a Telegram bot with PHP.

After sendPoll method boot it needs to wait 10 seconds for user answer - if user hasn't answered, the bot closes this Poll with method `stopPoll`. (Looks like Telegram's official @quizbot)

I use webhooks - the `stopPoll` method required `message_id` option for close Poll and I don't know how can I get the `message_id` of the latest `sendPoll` message in order to store it in the MySQL DB.

```
case '/sendpoll':
    $i = '';
    switch($i){ 
        case 0:
            $stt->sendteleg($data = ['text'=>"Are you ready? \xF0\x9F\x9A\x80"], $chat_id_call, "sendMessage");
            sleep(2);
            $dataSend = getpollquestions(0,6);
            $stt->sendteleg($dataSend, $chat_id_call, "sendPoll");
            $hasstate =$dbconn->hasuserstate($user_id_call);
            if($hasstate){
            $dbconn->updatestate($user_id_call,$message_id_call,'wait','poll');
            }else {$dbconn->adduserstate($user_id_call,$message_id_call,'wait','poll');}
            $state = $dbconn->getuserstate($user_id_call);
            $statebolim = explode("-_-",$state);
            sleep(10);
            $datalimit = gettimeplus10($statebolim[2]);

            if($datalimit){
            $dat = [
            'message_id' => json_encode($statebolim[0]+2)];
            $stt->sendteleg($dat, $chat_id_call, "stopPoll");
            }
```

You can see that I save `message_id` of the last `callbackbutton` that starts `Poll` in the DB and +2 it for `stopPoll` (+1 for "Are you ready" message and +1 for last `sendPoll` message). It's working, but there is exception if the user sends any message before the bot closes the Poll - `message_id` is wrong and `stopPoll` is not working.

Please tell me how can I make this code work?

Answer (score 0):

i found solution, sending message(or Poll) with

```
$info = file_get_contents($bot_url."/sendPoll?" .http_build_query($dataSend));
```

returns all information about this action(chat_id, message_id, poll_id etc);
you can get all info by saving $info ;